# Counting characters in a string with SSE Intrinsics

Tags: character, sse, frequency, intrinsics, counting

I am trying to implement a character-frequency function in C. This task is very simple of course, simply loop over the string and increment like this:

```
for(cycle = 0; cycle < length; cycle++){
    integer = line[cycle];
    bins[ integer*length+cycle ]++;
}
```

Now when doing this over a billion times or more (yes my files are that big), this part of the program becomes pretty time intensive as the array will have to be accessed 10e8 * length times.

I googled around for some time now and have found ample examples how to add, multiply, divide, etc with the use of registers, but as I am not the slightest familiar with SSE, MMX, etc. I have no idea how to implement character counting using these functions.

I am hoping to reduce the time spent in this function as 4 characters could be read simultaneously. Could you please show me in the right direction or even better present a piece of code?

Thanks in advance.
Mark

Comment: This task isn't very amenable to SSE right now. What you'll need are the gather/scatter instructions in AVX2. Currently there are no processors that support it yet.